# List of HashMap into JSONs string with new line in Java

Tags: java, jackson

I have to convert a List into jsons string with new line.

Right now the code which i am using converts the List of HashMap into single jsons string. like below:

```
List<HashMap> mapList= new ArrayList<>();
HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
hashmap.add("name","SO");
hashmap.add("rollNo","1");
mapList.put(hashmap);

HashMap hashmap1 = new HashMap();
hashmap1.add("name","SO1");
hashmap1.add("rollNo","2");
mapList.put(hashmap1 );
```

Now I am converting it into jsons string using ObjectMapper and the output would be

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(mapList);
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"SO","rollNo":1},{"name":"SO1","rollNo":2}]
```

Its working fine but I need the output inthe format shown below, i.e for every HashMap there should be new line in the JSON string.

```
[{"name":"SO","rollNo":1},
{"name":"SO1","rollNo":2}]
```

Comment: Any particular reason as to why you aren't mapping your `hashmap` and `hashmap1` to json and using a `StringBuilder` with `appendLine()`?

Comment: I already tried that but the issue was that in this case I have to append "[" and "]"    and comma manually. So is there any way to do it through ObjectMapper.

Comment: @IoannisBarakos thats a sudo code i wrote. HashMap is HashMap<String,Object>

Comment: @VinitK OK I thought it was a copy-paste code from your project and it was strange to me :)

Answer (score 0):

If i clearly understand the question, you can use:

```
output.replaceAll(",",",\n");
```

or you can go through each `HashMap.Entry` and call

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(entry);
```

or use configuration

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
```

Comment: That is not correct. The replaceAll will add a new line in each comma (,) and will produce funny results, imaging having commas inside the json string e.g. `hashmap.put("n,,,ame","SO");`  The second approach, to print each hashMap entry is not correct either as it will not print on a complete json.

Comment: `output.replace("},{", "},\r\n{");`  is not fool-proof, but near.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String methods to change/replace the output's String. However, this is not correct for json Strings as they may contain commas or other characters that you should escape in the String replace methods.

Alternatively, you should parse the Json String and use JsonNode on the Json as below:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(mapList);

    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(output);
    Iterator<JsonNode> iter=jsonNode.iterator();
     String result = "[";
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        result+=iter.next().toString() + ",\n";
    }
    result =result.substring(0,result.length()-2) + "]";
    System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
[{"rollNo":"1","name":"SO"},
{"rollNo":"2","name":"SO1"}]
```

This approach will work for String containing characters like comma, for example consider the input `hashmap.put("n,,,ame","SO");`

The result is:

```
[{"n,,,ame":"SO","rollNo":"1"},
{"rollNo":"2","name":"SO1"}]
```

Update: Output updated to include [ and ] and commas between rows.
Update: Fixed the output accordingly

Comment: This is missing the commas between the elements in the list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slightly different path, and that is use a custom serializer, as outlined [here](https://gist.github.com/deverton/7743979) for example.

It boils down to have your own

```
public static class MgetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Mget> {
```

Which works for List for example.

The point is: I would avoid to "mix" things, as: having a solution where your code writes part of the output, and jackson creates *other* parts of the output. Rather enable jackson to do exactly what you want it to do.

Beyond that, I find the whole approach a bit dubious in the first place. JSON strings do not care about newlines. So, if you care how things are formatted, rather look into the tools you are using to *look* at your JSON.

Meaning: why waste your time formatting a string that isn't **meant** for direct human consumption in the first place? Browser consoles will show you JSON strings in a "folded" way, and any decent editor has similar capabilities these days.

In other words: I think you are investing your energy in the wrong place. JSON is a transport format, and you should only worry about the **content** you want to transmit, not in (essentially meaningless formatting effects).

Comment: total idea is that I am using that json string in Spark Structured Streaming. Spark Structured streaming can only understand the list of json when they will be in seprate-2 line. Thats why i am looking a way to formatting json into new line.

Comment: @VinitK Then you should write a defect against that tool. JSON should be JSON, and "formatting" isn't part of that.